# Finding which files are taking up most space

Tags: macos, unix

On a mac terminal, I want to find out which files are the biggest in my project.

I try:

```
du -h | sort
```

But this sorts by path first and then within path the file size.  How do I do it just for file size?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
du -scm * | sort -n
```

If you want to have it as a nice zsh function you can use this:

```
function dudir () { du -scm ${1:-*(ND)} | sort -n }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort by numeric/reversed:

```
$ du -sk * | sort -nr
190560  find_buggy_pos.out
126676  DerivedData
29460   fens.txt
11108   cocos2d_html.tar.gz
484     ccore.log
164     ccore.out
16      a.out.dSYM
12      x
12      p
12      o
12      a.out
4       x.txt
4       trash.c
4       test2.cpp
4       test.cpp
4       stringify.py
4       ptest.c
4       o.cpp
4       mismatch.txt
4       games.pgn
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to list *files* by size.  Try:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n
```

(By default, `du` doesn't list counts for files.  Use the `-a` or `--all` option to list count for files as well.)

Comment: @MoreThanFive What doesn't work?  `find` or `printf` or `sort`?

Comment: I get: find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Answer (score 1):

On OSX following works:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec du -k {} \; | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-k` option:

```
du -sk * | sort -n
```

Comment: cool. Can you give me a switch so I get files and not just dirs?

Comment: @MoreThanFive, `du` does not provide *file only* option. Try `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs du -k | sort -n`.